# Breadth First Search: Directed Graph

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement BFS on directed graph. 
I am perfectly sure I got my algorithm correct, however, following piece of code is returning error:

Graph.CPP file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class node{
    int value;
    int color;


    public:
        list <node> adj;
        node(int val){
            value = val;
            color = 0;
        }

        void add_edge(node x){
            adj.push_back(x);
        }

        void change_color(int c){
            color = c;
        }

        int get_color(){
            return color;
        }

        int get_value(){
            return value;
        }
};
```

And Actual BFS Implementation IN:

```
#include "graph.cpp"
node n0(0),n1(1),n2(2),n3(3), n4(4);

//PrintQ: Print the list
void printq( list <node> A){
    while (!A.empty())
    {
        cout << A.front().get_value() <<" ";
        A.pop_front();
    }
}

void bfs(node s){
    list <node> q;
    q.push_back(s);
    s.change_color(1);

    while(!q.empty()){
        node s = q.front();

        cout<<s.get_value()<<'\t';
        printq(s.adj);      
        cout<<endl;

        list<node>::iterator i;
        for(i = s.adj.begin(); i != s.adj.end(); ++i){

            if((*i).get_color() == 0){
                q.push_back(*i);
                (*i).change_color(1);
            }
        }

        q.pop_front();
    }

}
int main(){

    n0.add_edge(n1);
    n0.add_edge(n2);
    n1.add_edge(n2);
    n2.add_edge(n0);
    n2.add_edge(n3);
    n0.add_edge(n3);
    n1.add_edge(n4);
    n4.add_edge(n3);
/*  
    printq(n0.adj);cout<<endl;
    printq(n1.adj);cout<<endl;
    printq(n2.adj);cout<<endl;
*/
    bfs(n1);

    return 0;
```

So, error appears that except source node, every other node in queue gives wrong adjacency list. While Queue order works perfectly, The nodes in queue give wrong adjacency.

I am not sure why it is happening, though I suspect it is due copy of nodes by value rather than reference.

This is my CPP program after a long interval, so if I am missing something, please enlighten me.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: "_I suspect it is due copy of nodes by value rather than reference_" - I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you exactly stated the problem. When you add 'n1.add_edge(n2);', n2 does not have any edge and n1 will keep a copy of n2. Later on, when you add more edges to n2, n1's copy does not change. I modified your code to use pointers and I think it works correctly now.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
class node{
    int value;
    int color;


    public:
        list <node * > adj;
        node(int val){
            value = val;
            color = 0;
        }

        void add_edge(node * x){
            adj.push_back(x);
        }

        void change_color(int c){
            color = c;
        }

        int get_color(){
            return color;
        }

        int get_value(){
            return value;
        }
};
```

and your main file

```
#include "graph.cpp"

//PrintQ: Print the list
void printq( list <node *> A){
    while (!A.empty())
    {
        cout << A.front()->get_value() <<" ";
        A.pop_front();
    }
}

void bfs(node * s){
    list <node *> q;
    q.push_back(s);
    s->change_color(1);

    while(!q.empty()){
        node * s = q.front();

        cout<<s->get_value()<<'\t';
        printq(s->adj);      
        cout<<endl;

        list<node * >::iterator i;
        for(i = s->adj.begin(); i != s->adj.end(); ++i){

            if((*i)->get_color() == 0){
                q.push_back(*i);
                (*i)->change_color(1);
            }
        }

        q.pop_front();
    }

}
int main(){

    node* n0 = new node(0);
    node* n1 = new node(1);
    node* n2 = new node(2);
    node* n3 = new node(3);
    node* n4 = new node(4);

    n0->add_edge(n1);
    n0->add_edge(n2);
    n1->add_edge(n2);
    n2->add_edge(n0);
    n2->add_edge(n3);
    n0->add_edge(n3);
    n1->add_edge(n4);
    n4->add_edge(n3);
/*  
    printq(n0.adj);cout<<endl;
    printq(n1.adj);cout<<endl;
    printq(n2.adj);cout<<endl;
*/
    bfs(n1);
    delete n0, n1, n2, n3, n4;
}
```